# rotating image in perspective view

Tags: c++, graphics

I am writing an album viewing program, which is able to view photos just like in 3d space. 
The underlying graphic toolkit is AntiGrain. It implements a [trans_perspective](http://www.antigrain.com/__code/include/agg_trans_perspective.h.html) transformer to do 2d perspective transformation. Generally, trans_perspective transforms 2D planar onto a square "in space". I've also added methods to rotate around x/y/z axis.
Basically, I want to rotate a image in perspective view. For example, in Qt's "svg viewer"(doc.qt.nokia.com/4.1/painting-svgviewer.html), the rotating Qt logo on the bottom. It rotates in a perspective view. I tried rotating around x-axes to have a perspective view, but I cannot simply use the rotation around other axes to rotate the image in perspective view, since the coordinate system has already been changed.

Comment: you may need to be more specific to get better answers.

Comment: @tenfour : for example, in Qt's "svg viewer"(http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.1/painting-svgviewer.html), the rotating Qt logo on the bottom. It rotates in a perspective view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to translate the object to the origin, apply the rotation, then translate the object back to the original spot.  This will rotate the object around its center.

Comment: well, I think that only applies to 2d rotation case(rotating around z-axes for the case).

Comment: It works for any rotation. Maybe I'm not clear on your problem, but the perspective transformation is applied after all the others.